# defaultDate and minDate with Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want a picker to be set to a month in the future by default. This works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#enddatepicker').datetimepicker({
      defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'M').toDate(),
      locale: 'de',
      format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, I also want the date to be not before tomorrow. So I try adding a minDate option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#enddatepicker').datetimepicker({
      minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(),
      defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'M').toDate(),
      locale: 'de',
      format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    });
  });
</script>
```

However, now the default date is set to minDate (that is, tomorrow). Can I set a default date independently from the minimum date?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looking at the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L1674) (line 1674) if you set the option [useCurrent](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) to false, your default may not be overridden:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $('#enddatepicker').datetimepicker({
       useCurrent: false,
       minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(),
       defaultDate: moment().add(1, 'M').toDate(),
       locale: 'de',
       format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
     });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out for me! Would you say I still should raise an issue (at least for the situation to be explicitly documented)?

Comment: That's not a bad idea. If the documentation is amended then to clarify then others may not have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would [raise an issue in github](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues) for this, as `minDate` should not override `defaultDate`. In the mean-time, all you can do is set the value explicitly:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#enddatepicker').datetimepicker({
         minDate: moment().add(1, 'd').toDate(),
         locale: 'de',
         format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    });
     $('#enddatepicker').val(moment().add(1, 'M').format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="demo col-xs-6">
       <input class="form-control" id="enddatepicker"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `minDate` overrides `defaultDate` on purpose. If `min/maxDate` is before or after the `defaultDate` then `defaultDate` is an invalid date according to the options set

Answer (score -2):

Try with Start Date property, after checked my jquery i found that has not minDate parameter but startDate parameter to handle minDate.it will work for you.

startDate :new Date(),

skype @lokesh7676 to get more help

Comment: -1 because... 1) The answer seems to be incorrect, AFAICT the API is still `minDate` and not `startDate`, perhaps you're confusing it with a different library? 2) Posting your Skype does not help visitors directly. StackOverflow is not intended for this, feel free to mention it on your profile. 3) The post lacks in formatting and grammar.